# How to prodive friend(link) recommendation in social network using mahout

Tags: social-networking, mahout

Does anyone know how to use the mahout library to provide friend(link) recommendations in a social network? Directed or undirected that could possibly have (only?) positive but also negative links.

Such as the ones found [at Standford](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/#socnets).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question the answer is yes. I mined a bunch of "pinned people" from Pinterest and created a recommender using Mahout. It showed up some pretty interesting recs that convinced me it was working.

If you treat the action as "friending" then the data is: (user-doing-the-friending, user-friended) Use a boolean item based recommender with LLR as the similarity measure et voila.

Using negative links is tougher. The obvious thing is to filter an individual's recs by the negative links for a that user. Another might be to create "friending" recs and "hating" recs separately then filter an individual's friending recs by their hating recs.

BTW epinions data is often used as a base test set for the collaborative filtering code in Mahout.